# array in R number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop, cbind

I would like to ask, how to set a value in array using looping. say like this

```
a<-3
b<-4
for( i in 1:5)
{
  x[i] <- cbind(a*i, b*i)
}
```

but i always get error saying : In x[i] <- cbind(a * i, b * i) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. I used "paste" but seems it's not the solution. What is the problem ? If it were solved, can I get the value by using ; for example x[2][,2] to get the value of b * 2 ?
thank you

Comment: You shouldn't use for loops in R to grow an array. Try to do `x = a * c(1:5)` instead. I'm not sure what exactly you're doing in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
a <- 3
b <- 4
i <- 1:5
x <- cbind(a*i, b*i)
```

Comment: Wow. never thought it will be that simple. thank you !

Comment: what a convenient language indeed ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the matrix functions and the fact that R computes directly on vectors and matrices.

In your case, try this:

```
outer(1:5, 3:4, FUN = "*")

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    6    8
[3,]    9   12
[4,]   12   16
[5,]   15   20
```

Comment: never use that "outer" before. new knowledge for me. Thank you